# How to set current user's attribute in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Android Studio, I have created an app with successful sign up and log in. When the user signs up, the user is saved in the Firebase with attributes name, email, phone number, gender etc. 
I want to be able to retrieve the attributes when the user logs in. Let's say gender of the current user. In Firebase documentation, I can only find a way to retrieve the name, email and phoneURL.

How do I retrieve the other attributes?

Firebase Documentation:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

String name = user.getDisplayName();

String email = user.getEmail();

Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put - you **can not** set attributes to Firebase Auth `user` object. There are predefined attributes that facilitate access to user information, especially when using a provider (such as Google sign in).

Instead of this, if you need to store more information about a user, use the Firebase realtime database.

For example, you can have a `/Users` parent, that contains all the `userId` of the users as children. Then, you can store the attributes that you need for the user, such as age, gender, and so on.

> When the user signs up, the user is saved in the Firebase with attributes name, email, phone number, gender etc.

^ This is not the default behaviour. But, as I mentioned, you can save this and any other user information in a your Realtime Database node at the time of a user's sign up.